# How to avoid duplicate lists in List<List<Integer>> in java

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist, set

Such that, [2,2,3] & [2,3,2] both should not occur in it.

What I'm doing in the code is given a set [2, 3, 6, 7] and target 7, I find unique combinations where candidate numbers sums to target

Output:

[

[7],

[2, 2, 3]

]
The code is working fine but I feel I'm using a complicated way by creating `HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>>`, using Collection.sort() to avoid duplicates lists. Is there a better way I could avoid that?

```
 HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>> set= new HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        public List<List<Integer>> combinationSum(int[] candidates, int target) {        
            backtract(candidates,target,0, new ArrayList<Integer>(),0);   

            List<List<Integer>> output=new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(set);
            return output;
        }



 public void backtract(int[] candidates, int target, int pos, List<Integer> list, int sum){
        if(sum==target){
            ArrayList l=new ArrayList<Integer>(list);     

            Collections.sort(l);
            set.add(l);
         }

    for(int i=0;i<candidates.length;i++){
        if(sum+candidates[i] > target){
            continue;
        }
        sum=sum+candidates[i];           
        list.add(candidates[i]);
        backtract(candidates,target,i+1, list,sum);
        list.remove(new Integer(candidates[i]));
        sum=sum-candidates[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `List<List<Set>>`, nothing complicated about it, duplicate items won't be added.

Comment: Try something like **Sum of Subset Algorithm**

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible way to it.

```
public static void backtract(int[] candidates, int target, int pos, List<Integer> list, int sum) {
    if(sum == target){
        finalOutput.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(list));
        return;
    }

    for (int i = pos; i < candidates.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= (target - sum) / candidates[i]; j++) {
            List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>(list);
            for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
                newList.add(candidates[i]);
            }
            backtract(candidates, target, i + 1, newList, sum + (candidates[i] * j));
        }
    }
}
```

The main challenge in this problem is allowing a particular element to be picked up more than once.

So, the idea (in the above code) is to keep moving forward on each recursive call. In your code, each recursive call started at the element at index 0, which was the reason to that led to duplicates. Here, each recursive calls starts at the element at index `pos`.

To pick a particular element more than once, we check how many of it (the current element) can contribute to the overall (remaining) target by checking `(target - sum) / candidates[i]` (let this be `ct`). So, we make recursive calls by picking *1, 2, 3... ct* of them (adding to the current sum).

Some points:

1. To avoid mutating the array, I create new ones to simplify the code. You can change it if it proves to be affecting the performance.
2. I have kept `finalOutput` as a static variable. You can pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

REFACTORING TO A CLASS

REFACTORING TO A CLASS
This refactoring uses a class instead of a set of static methods.
COSTANT FIELDS : The parameters 'target' and 'candidate' and its length are constants in this class and it became fields here.
NOT USED PARAMETERS: The parameters 'pos' is never used and was removed. The 'list' can become a field and is not needed as parameter.

OUTCOMES OF REFACTORING

- It is easier to distinguish the costants from the variables.
- The backtract method has only one parameter instead of five now.
- The {if - continue} was removed by inverting the condition to :   if (target >= sum + cnd) .

IF YOU GIVE MORE HINTS
we could attempt with a complete new paradigm.

MORE
It would be kind if you give more hints on the backtracking and what

- you want to achieve ie the use case
- what is the semantic meaning of the input
- what is the semantic meaning of the desired output
- what are the limits and ranges on the methods parameters
- what are the class invariants and document them
- what are and method invariants and document them

Something about invariants and why they are used: [ADT invariants replace preconditions](https://web.mit.edu/6.031/www/sp21/classes/11-abstraction-functions-rep-invariants/#adt_invariants_replace_preconditions)

When you have completed the above steps you will have a well formed ADT - abstract data type - on which you can easier reason about your algorithm: its correctness first. And its performance, thread-safety  too. And it will be "Safe from bugs", "Easy to understand", "Ready for change".

DUPLICATE LISTS
You are right that a set of lists will not add duplicate lists, like in this example:

```
    List<Integer> A = List.of(1, 2, 3);
    List<Integer> B = List.of(9, 8, 11, 7, 8);
    List<Integer> duplicateOfA = List.of(1, 2, 3);

    Set<List<Integer>> lists = new HashSet<>();
    
    lists.add(A);
    lists.add(duplicateOfA);
    lists.add(B);
    
    System.out.println(lists);
```